# Matching more entries in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames of this form

```
 df1<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3))

 df1: 

 A   
 1    
 2    
 3  

 df2<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,7),B=c(cat,dog,cat,dog,cat,cat,dog,dog))

 df2:   
 A  B  
 1 cat  
 2 dog  
 3 cat   
 1 dog   
 2 cat  
 4 cat   
 5 dog  
 7 dog
```

I want to create a third data frame of this form

```
  dataframe3   
  A B    
  1 cat  
  2 dog  
  3 cat  
  1 dog  
  2 cat
```

In other words, I want to keep all the observations in the second data frame which match with the ones in the dataframe1. However, if I use the match function it returns me just the first "common" entry between the two data frames, while I want all the entries in common between the two.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by="A")`

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
A
1
2
3
", header=T)

df2 = read.table(text = "
A B
1 cat
2 dog
3 cat
1 dog
2 cat
4 cat
5 dog
7 dog
", header=T)

df2[df2$A %in% df1$A,]

#   A   B
# 1 1 cat
# 2 2 dog
# 3 3 cat
# 4 1 dog
# 5 2 cat
```